# MS Graph .net SDK cannot expand calendar event SingleValueExtendedProperties

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, outlook-calendar

I need to read a certain `SingleValueExtendedProperty` from a calendar event.

I'm already doing that in a Teams Tab app and in the Graph explorer webpage, but somehow I can't using the ms graph sdk for .net.

Reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request) I need to expand the `SingleValueExtendedProperties` property filtering by `id`.

```
string idTest = "String {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx} Name nameofproperty";

Event result = await _graphServiceClient.Users[email].Events[eventId].Request()
                                                                     .Expand($"singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq '{idTest}')")
                                                                     .GetAsync();
```

Comment: Does it throw any exception or singleValueExtendedProperties is null in the response?

Comment: @user2250152 it does not, the result of the request is the Event, but its SingleValueExtendedProperties value is null. 
The same query from the teams application works fine